# AliasMatch everything except home page to "content" folder

Tags: regex, apache, apache2.4

I am putting all of my website's content (aside from the home page) into a "content" folder at the root of the site. This is Apache 2.4.25.

I want `http://www.example.com` to serve the `DirectoryIndex` (i.e. `index.html`) at `C:/DocumentRoot/`. The following works fine for that.

```
<Directory "C:/DocumentRoot/website">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I then want to have `http://www.example.com/anything1/anything2` serve the `DirectoryIndex` at `C:/DocumentRoot/content/anything1/anything2`. After adding the following, accessing `http://www.example.com` gives a `Forbidden` error, though the `AliasMatch` works.

```
AliasMatch "^/(.+)$" "C:/DocumentRoot/website/content/$1"
<Directory "C:/DocumentRoot/website/content/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any idea what's happening or have a better/working alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change to the `AliasMatch` so it ignores the `DirectoryIndex` (`index.html`) allows it to work as expected.

```
AliasMatch "^/(?!index.html)(.+)$" "C:/DocumentRoot/website/content/$1"
```

`(?!index.html)` ensures that the implicit `index.html` is not matched. The `(.+)` picks up anything else and pulls it from the `content` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, mod_rewrite is a little easier to read and later extend then a negative assertion regex in the AliasMatch.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content
RewriteRule ^/(.+) "C:/DocumentRoot/website/content/$1"
```

Comment: With this, shouldn't `http://www.example.com/help` pull up the content at `C:/DocumentRoot/website/content/help`? I tried your answer after `Require all granted` in the either `Directory` section I listed (I removed the `AliasMatch` first).